# How do I merge two heads on Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

Please, help me! I'm not familiar with Mercurial.
I have a message in my bitbucket telling me that my "default branch has multiple [two] heads", which is not what I want. The branches are both labeled "Default." I've tried *hg merge* and I get "abort: nothing to merge."

When I do *hg heads*, only one gets listed.

```
changeset:   4:fb6f0d961015
tag:         tip
user:        Name <my_email>
date:        Fri Feb 07 03:39:23 2014 -0800
summary:     Folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you pulled changes from the server?  It sounds like you have one head locally, but when your changes are combined with what is on the server it produces two heads...

If your changes 'C' are based on change 'B', but someone else has also made change 'D' based on 'B' ...

```
C  D
|  |
B /
|
A
```

You see A-B-C on your machine (only one head), but when it is pushed to the server it would create two.
If that is the case, you need to pull the latest changes from the server and then do the merge.

Answer (score 0):

If you just performed a `hg pull` you probably just need to do

```
hg update -r <revision>
```

where  is the one that resulted from pulling. In general you may find it convinient to combine the two operation with

```
hg pull -u <repository>
```